# distribution of a vector (U,V)

Tags: statistics, beta, chi-squared

I'm struggling with the following statistics exercise, any help would be really appreciated

find the distribution of the vector (U,V) given that

- U = X*Y and V = (1-X)*Y
- X and Y are independent
- X assumes beta distribution with parameters (a1,a2)
- Y assumes chi-squared distribution with parameter 2*(a1+a2)

Comment: Start making substitutions: (beta(a1, a2)*chi(2*(a1+a2), (1-beta(a1, a2))*chi(2*(a1+a2)))).  Then start plotting U and V contour plots in the plane.

Comment: Thanks Duffy, I'm taking computational approachs to understand the function but the thing I need is to write the math.

Comment: I think a contour plot will help a great deal.  Beta and chi-squared functions aren't intuitive to most people.